# Running django-hunger together with django-allauth

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

I'm using `django-hunger` together with `django-allauth`. The allauth setup works on its own.

When enabling `django-hunger`, I get redirects on socialaccount urls (which is normal, this is how it works), but I have problems enabling the view modules for the social accounts eg. twitter.

This is what I have.

```
HUNGER_ALWAYS_ALLOW_MODULES = [
        "django.contrib.auth.views",
        "allauth.account.views", 
        "allauth.socialaccount.views",
        "allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter.views",
    ]
```

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: do you see your urls in "manage.py show_urls" (it's a django-extensions command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add oauth and oauth2 modules

```
"allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth.views",
"allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.views",
```

Comment: just to be clear, these need to go in HUNGER_ALWAYS_ALLOW_MODULES NOT HUNGER_ALWAYS_ALLOW_VIEWS